# gradle init script task not invoked : Gradle 2.14.1

Tags: gradle, init

Please find below init.gradle file that has a common task for all my projects :-

```
rootProject { apply plugin: "eclipse" }

gradle.allprojects{
    ext.commonTaskForEveryBuild = {
        println "Common task for every build starts here..."
        println "Common task for every build ends here..."
    }
}
```

Also find below sample build.gradle for one of my project :-

```
apply plugin : 'java'

clean.doFirst{
    println "Before invoking commonTaskForEveryBuild"  

    //This is invocation of commonTaskForEveryBuild
    commonTaskForEveryBuild

    println "After invoking commonTaskForEveryBuild"
}
```

Below are the logs for the execution of "gradle clean" task for the sample build.gradle file :-

> :clean
>
> Before invoking commonTaskForEveryBuild
>
> After invoking
> commonTaskForEveryBuild
>
> :clean UP-TO-DATE
>
> BUILD SUCCESSFUL
>
> Total time: 3.722 secs

Looks like clean.doFirst is called, but it's not invoking definition of commonTaskForEveryBuild. Although, there is no compile time or runtime error.
Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's all right, that your task is not invoked, since your script doesn't attempt to do it and it's not even a task. You just getting your `commonTaskForEveryBuild` instance, but do nothing with it.

You may need to read [the official user guide](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html#sec:adding_dependencies_to_tasks) to find out, how to call one task from another. In short - this is usually done via task dependencies. You have to make your `clean` task depending on `commonTaskForEveryBuild` task to run it before the `clean` task execution. This could be done like so:

```
clean.dependsOn commonTaskForEveryBuild
```

Furthermore, it's all about tasks, but in your case `ext.commonTaskForEveryBuild = {...}` is not even a task, but just a closure and it must be executed as `commonTaskForEveryBuild()`